# Decode html parameter in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I get the name of a file from a notification between one pluggin and my cocoa application. My problem is that I am receiving the file name like this: "My+file+name.png" instead of "My file name.png" (with spaces). I don't know how to decode this parameter in order to get the correct file name.
Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is encoded as for a URL query string, you'll want to [replace any plus signs with spaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3a) and [unescape the percent escape sequences](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the javascript code from my pluggin. I added this function:

```
function decode(str) {
    return unescape(str.replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

I called before passing the parameters to my cocoa application.